# Setting default language to 'JavaScript' doesn't actually set it

Tags: notepad++, file-association, default-settings

I'm using Notepad++ v7.5.8 (64 bit) on Windows 10.

I set my default language to `Batch`.

After creating a new doc, typing some code and hitting save - it'll automatically select `*.bat` as the file type.

[image]

<sup>Notice how it automatically chose those file types (by **Save as type:**)</sup>

---

However, this is not the case when I select JavaScript, it just shows **`All types (*.*)`**

[image]

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong when I change it.

<sup>(It does the correct syntax highlighting, just not the save as)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I take it you type a new document and then save it.

Before saving, set in the Language menu the language to JavaScript,
and then Notepad++ will suggest JavaScript file-extensions.

[image]

Comment: However, I have to do this manually... the point of the default is to do it automatically (it does that when I select Batch)

Comment: JavaScript has too many variants, unfortunately.